# Can fastlane deliver distinguish between iPad Pro (6th generation) and iPad Pro (2nd generation)?

Tags: fastlane, fastlane-deliver, frameit

I just tried `frameit` and realized it doesn't distinguish between iPad Pros of the same size. I wanted to confirm that `deliver` could make that distinction.

Also, when using `frameit` and `deliver` in a `Fastfile`, is there a flag to ignore (or delete) non framed images? (I didn't find an example of using `frameit` in a `Fastfile`)

```
platform :ios do
  desc "Generate new localized screenshots"
  lane :screenshots do
    capture_screenshots(scheme: "AppUITests")
    # frameit?
    upload_to_app_store(skip_binary_upload: true, skip_metadata: true, overwrite_screenshots: true)
  end
```